# is there any way to cancel all existing promises a view when a Navigation .pop is done?

Tags: flutter

I have a view where I am trying to make an http request. this request takes several seconds and as a result a `dialog` will open, if at this time my web request is still not resolved, and I navigate a page back (`pop`) this web request will continue to run, how can I cancel it so that it does not the `dialog` is displayed?

```
final url = Uri.parse(url_webservice);
try {
 final Map<String, String> headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 };

 var response = await http
    .post(url, headers: headers, body: args)
 var document = json.decode(response.body);
 mostrarAlertError(context, "message", 500)
 print("respuestapeticion" + document.toString());
 if (response.statusCode == 401 || response.statusCode == 500) {

 }
 return document;
} catch (exception) {
}
```

my dialog code:

```
 void mostrarAlertError(BuildContext context, String mensaje, int statusCode) 
 {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (context) {
          return FadeInDown(
            child: AlertDialog(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
              title: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: STYLES.styles["danger"]["color"],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(19.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(19.0),
                  ),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 5),
                child: Text(
                  'Error',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
                    child: FadeInUp(
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.error,
                          size: 50,
                          color: STYLES.styles["danger"]["color"],
                        )),
                  ),
                  Text(mensaje),
                ],
              ),
              titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Aceptar'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      /*=> statusCode == 500
                      ? Navigator.of(context).pop()
                      : logout(context),*/

                      if (statusCode == 500) {
                        return Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      } else {
                        return logout(context);
                      }
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once a Future is started in Dart, there is no way to cancel it. You can use a `CancelableOperation` from the `async` package which prevents the value from being completed.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/CancelableOperation-class.html

Comment: Excuse me, but I still don't understand. thanks for your help. but how can this help me just when I navigate to another screen?

Comment: Can you post your UI code including how and where you call the dialog?